# How to check if a user is already logged in using google.accounts.id

Tags: google-signin, google-api-js-client

I am migrating to the new-ish google auth api based on `google.accounts.id` and documented here https://developers.google.com/identity/gsi/web/guides/display-button

Using the old API I was able to check if a user was logged in before displaying the login button using `gapi.auth2.getAuthInstance().isSignedIn.get()`.

What is the equivalent with this new `google.accounts.id` approach?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to their docs, that method has been removed and it's now up to you to directly manage the state of a user's session state: https://developers.google.com/identity/oauth2/web/guides/migration-to-gis?authuser=1#session_state.

I'm dealing with the same issue as you and found this possible workaround using a Cookie instead to track the user's session state. It might be helpful in your situation: https://stackoverflow.com/a/68855272/8056536